# Clipping by looping through list using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, clip

I'm having trouble creating a looping function that looks through a geodatabase, clips each feature class to a "study_area" polygon, and puts the clipped files in a separate geodatabase. I keep getting "Could not clip feature classes". The features can all be clipped individually but trying to run this loop doesn't work.

What am I missing here?

I tried to search for similar questions but only found answers regarding raster clips. Code below.

```
from arcpy import env


# setting my source and target geodatabase 
SourceWorkspace = r"E:\UFD Commercial Corridor\Roosevelt.gdb"
TargetWorkspace = r"E:\UFD Commercial Corridor\Clipped.gdb"

#setting my clip feature (which is a polygon)
clipfeature = r"E:\UFD Commercial Corridor\Clip area.gdb\study_area"

env.workspace = SourceWorkspace

try:
    fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

    for fc in fcList:
        outClipFeatureClass = targetWorkspace + "//Studyarea_" + fc

        arcpy.Clip_analysis(fc,clipfeature,outClipFeatureClass)

except: 
    arcpy.AddError("Could not clip feature classes")
    print ("could not clip feature classes")
    print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

Comment: It's bad practice to wrap things in a bare try/except block because it obscures any errors that you weren't expecting.  If you remove that then at least one of the issues @Aaron mentions should become obvious

Comment: I removed that block and revised in accordance with @Aaron's guidance, but the clip is still failing. I'm getting the following error "Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 20, in <module>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.7\arcpy\arcpy\analysis.py", line 62, in Clip     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 999998: Unexpected Error." 


Lines 17-20 are as follows: 
`for fc in fcList:
 outClipFeatureClass = os.path.join(TargetWorkspace, "study_area_" + fc)

 arcpy.Clip_analysis(fc, clipfeature, outClipFeatureClass)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two problems:

1. you are defining `TargetWorkspace` though you are calling `targetWorkspace`. Python is case-sensitive.
2. You need to properly join together strings to create paths. I highly recommend becoming familiar with [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join). For example

Instead of:

```
outClipFeatureClass = targetWorkspace + "//Studyarea_" + fc
```

Use:

```
outClipFeatureClass = os.path.join(TargetWorkspace, "Studyarea_" + fc)
```

---

```
import arcpy
import os

# setting my source and target geodatabase 
SourceWorkspace = r"E:\UFD Commercial Corridor\Roosevelt.gdb"
TargetWorkspace = r"E:\UFD Commercial Corridor\Clipped.gdb"

#setting my clip feature (which is a polygon)
clipfeature = r"E:\UFD Commercial Corridor\Clip area.gdb\study_area"

env.workspace = SourceWorkspace

fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for fc in fcList:
    outClipFeatureClass = os.path.join(TargetWorkspace, "Studyarea_" + fc)
    arcpy.Clip_analysis(fc,clipfeature,outClipFeatureClass)
```